# Move image inside div text using hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to imitate [this project in jsfiddle](https://codepen.io/dghez/pen/ItxKE#anon-login) and how do I do this hover effect inside my `React project` without using `jquery`. Here's my current `script tag : <script src="/umi.js"></script>` in `index.html`. Is there any way to implement this effect without having to include `<script>`?
Here's my css code:

```css
.bigTitle{
  font-weight: 800;
  color: transparent;
  font-size:120px;
  background: url("https://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/rainbow-nebula.jpg") repeat;
  background-position: 40% 50%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:90px;
  letter-spacing: -8px;
}
```

I would want the image inside the text to **react according to my mouse position**.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

const mouseMove = (e) => {
  let mouseX, mouseY;
  let traX, traY;
  mouseX = e.pageX;
  mouseY = e.pageY;
  traX = ((4 * mouseX) / 570) + 40;
  traY = ((4 * mouseY) / 570) + 50;
  document.getElementById('bigTitle').style.backgroundPosition = traX + "%" + traY + "%";
}
```

```css
#bigTitle{
  font-weight: 800;
  color: transparent;
  font-size:120px;
  background: url("https://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/rainbow-nebula.jpg") repeat;
  background-position: 40% 50%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:90px;
  letter-spacing: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigTitle" onmousemove="mouseMove(event)">It works?</div>
```

This should do it, I just translated whatever it was in the example you provided in javascript.